# Space between buttons not visible on small screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I was making the HomeScreen of my application. After I finished it was the perfect on Design Screen. But it doesn't look anything like that in the Pixel 3a emulator and even worse on my Xiaomi Redmi 4x. How can make it look like Design Screen variant both on the emulator and on my phone.

I tried using ConstraintLayout with View but it didn't work. Any other solutions?

Here is the screenshot's
[image: Desing Screen]

[image: Pixel 3a emulator]

[image: Phone Redmi 4X]
I have uploaded screenshot but it doesn't seem to work

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_screen_image"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".HomeScreen">
    <!--    tools:openDrawer="start"-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/purple_200"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/homeScreenLogo"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/kaznau_logo"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btnAboutUniversity"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_university"
            android:text="@string/s_about_kaznau"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:cornerRadius="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/homeScreenLogo" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btnFaculties"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_faculty"
            android:text="Факультет"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:cornerRadius="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btnAboutUniversity"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnAboutUniversity" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btnNews"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_article_24"
            android:text="@string/s_news"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:cornerRadius="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnAboutUniversity" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btnEvents"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_event_24"
            android:text="@string/events_name"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:cornerRadius="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btnNews"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnNews" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btnLocations"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_location"
            android:text="@string/s_locations"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:cornerRadius="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnNews" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btnCampus"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_campus"
            android:text="@string/s_campus"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:cornerRadius="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btnLocations"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnLocations" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btnLinks"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_links"
            android:text="@string/s_links"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:cornerRadius="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnLocations" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btnContacts"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_contacts"
            android:text="@string/s_contacs"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:cornerRadius="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btnLinks"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnLinks" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btnAgrodamu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/s_agrodamu"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:cornerRadius="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnLinks" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: You can use guidelines in your constraint layout. Try my answer below it will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend to provide fixed values in the layout which is the reason why it is getting distorted on screen sizes with different densities, rather work with percentage.
Also no need to provide outer edge margins to your buttons since you have already provided padding to parent(ConstraintLayout). Just provide left margin to right column buttons.
Here is something very similar I would approach. This is for one of the buttons, you can apply the same to rest. Also please refer to the width and bias attributes specifically and adjust them as per your design.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btnFaculties"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_faculty"
            android:text="Факультет"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:cornerRadius="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btnAboutUniversity"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnAboutUniversity" 
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.2" 
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Most convenient way of doing is to add **guideline** in the center in your **`Constraint Layout`** and align your views with the **`guideline`** from left or right. In this way no matter what the screen size is your layout won't get disturbed.

Let's try it this way:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/main_screen_image"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".HomeScreen">
<!--    tools:openDrawer="start"-->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/purple_200"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</LinearLayout>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp">

 <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline39"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.50" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/homeScreenLogo"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/kaznau_logo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnAboutUniversity"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_university"
        android:text="@string/s_about_kaznau"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:cornerRadius="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline39"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/homeScreenLogo" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnFaculties"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_faculty"
        android:text="Факультет"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:cornerRadius="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline39"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btnAboutUniversity"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnAboutUniversity" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnNews"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_article_24"
        android:text="@string/s_news"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:cornerRadius="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline39"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnAboutUniversity" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnEvents"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_event_24"
        android:text="@string/events_name"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:cornerRadius="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline39"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btnNews"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnNews" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnLocations"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_location"
        android:text="@string/s_locations"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:cornerRadius="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline39"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnNews" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnCampus"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_campus"
        android:text="@string/s_campus"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:cornerRadius="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline39"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btnLocations"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnLocations" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnLinks"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_links"
        android:text="@string/s_links"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:cornerRadius="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline39"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnLocations" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnContacts"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_contacts"
        android:text="@string/s_contacs"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:cornerRadius="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline39"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btnLinks"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnLinks" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnAgrodamu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/s_agrodamu"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:cornerRadius="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnLinks" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Tried that, didn't helped. Buttons still jummed together on my phone. On emulator there is a little space, but still not like in Desing Screen

Comment: @Akzhan where did they jumped? I tried your code with guideline it's working perfectly. I tried and designed this on 5.0' screen size. Going below this size is going to disturb your views because you have given fixed width to your buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Change  `android:layout_width="160dp"` to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to all the those material buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Use match Constraints (0dp) instead of a fixed value and use a guideline at the center like this

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" //this is important
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Now give a margin to your buttons from the guideline(8dp or so ) and a margin from the parent and use match constraints.